# C Function returns (null) instead of returning an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to return a two dimensional array from a function. This code keeps returning null or it returns the a random address in hexadecimal. How can I return an array of hashes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **createBoard();

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s", *createBoard(3));
}

char **createBoard()
{
    char** aa = malloc(sizeof(char[2]));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            aa[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    free(aa);

    return aa;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, you must not use what is freed.

Comment: I'd guess the compiler is free to optimize away everything because use-after-free is statically provable and undefined behavior.

Comment: You said "How can I return an array of hashes?", but your code seems trying to return an array of arrays of hashes. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: There are some important questions you should consider. What data are you expecting to access with the `aa[i][j]` expression? Do you know how this subexpression is interpreted with respect to the declared type of `aa`, being `(char **)`? Do you know, how much memory you allocate for `aa`? Did you make sure it is sufficient for your application?

Comment: A double pointer is not the type of a 2D array, nor is it the pointer type to which a 2D array type decays.  The code allocates space large enough only for two `char`s, and assigns it to a pointer-to-pointer.  Dereferencing that at all produces undefined behavior, and dereferencing the result of *that* produces trebly-undefined behavior.  Also, `printf("%s", x)` requires `x` to point to a *null-terminated* string.  Not to mention, as your first comment already does, that the allocated space must not be freed before the program is done using it.

Comment: `char** aa = malloc(sizeof(char[2]));` make no sense.  Consider `aa = malloc(sizeof
 *aa);`

Answer (score 2):

A C function cannot return an array. What your function is returning is a pointer.

The most obvious problem is that you `free` the pointer just before returning its value. That deallocates whatever the pointer points to, and the pointer value itself becomes invalid. (It's not going to be a null pointer, just an invalid one.)

```
char** aa = malloc(sizeof(char[2]));
```

This allocates space for an array of 2 `char` objects (assuming `malloc` doesn't fail, you should check that). You need `sizeof(char*[2])` to allocate space for two `char*` pointer objects. Even then, it *doesn't* allocate space to hold any actual character data. With that fix, you've created two `char*` pointers, but you haven't created anything for them to point to. So `aa[0]` and `aa[1]` are `char*` pointer objects, but their values are garbage.

So this assignment:

```
aa[i][j] = '#';
```

tries to write to memory pointed to by a garbage pointer.

Even if you allocated memory for the character arrays, you've assigned the elements of each 3-element character array the value `'#'`. There's no null terminator, so if you try to treat that array as a string, you'll have undefined behavior. Most likely your `printf` call would traverse memory search for a `'\0'` character until it happens to find one -- or until it blows up because it doesn't have permission to access that memory.

(Using a `char**` to refer to an array of strings is fine. It's the same thing that's done for `argv` in `main`. You just have to allocate it correctly.)

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Quite right. (I was scrolling back and forth and I must have gotten that from another answer rather than from the question). Fixed.

Comment: There is no reason for `malloc(2)` to fail. AFAIK `malloc()` behavior is implementation defined for size equal zero, when it may return `NULL` or some other pointer (in which case the pointer must not be dereferenced, but should be `free`d). For non-zero size, however, `malloc()` is expecrted to return a valid pointer to an allocated block, as long as there was enough free memory for the allocation requested.

Comment: @CiaPan: "*as long as there was enough free memory for the allocation requested*". That's precisely why it can fail. Now it's unlikely that a single very small allocation will fail, but just as a matter of style you should always check. `malloc` is specified to return a null pointer on failure. (Linux has some issues with the [overcommit feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441364/10454), but that's another story.)

Answer (score -1):

I got segmentation Fault by executing your code.

There are still some problems like memory leak and ignoring the arugment `3`, but this code won't crash unless `malloc()` or `calloc()` fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **createBoard();

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s", *createBoard(3));
}

char **createBoard()
{
    /* pointers will be stored, so the size calculation should be based of size of pointers */
    char** aa = malloc(sizeof(char*[2]));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        /* allocate buffer for storeing the hashes */
        /* don't forget to allocate an extra element for terminating null-character */
        aa[i] = calloc(4, sizeof(char));
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            aa[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    /* the contents of aa will be used after being returned, so you must not free that */

    return aa;
}
```